# how to pre-load the iframe content(an aspx page)in asynchronous mode for faster loading

Tags: c#, javascript, css

Hi I have a page called "compare.aspx" with a magnifier image, now when i click the magnifier for the first time, i want to load the page "abc.aspx" inside the iframe  named "security" but i want the iframe to remain hidden for the first time. With this small trick, when user click over magnifier, page is already loaded. How can i achieve this functionality?,, my iframe looks like:

```
<iframe id="security" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="100%" scrolling="no" src="/img/pqr.gif"></iframe>
```

Comment: Where's your code? You forgot to add it

Comment: @rsplak, no he just didn't click the {} button

Comment: can't you simply play with the style visibility attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a high level, what you will do is:

1) Browsers frown on hidden iframes, but a workaround is to use a 0 opacity frame. Start at 0 opacity. (Well, one or the other - I sometimes forget which is right).

2) On Click of your magnifier, set the src attribute of your iframe to your aspx page.

3) When ready, set the opacity of your frame to 1 (fully visible).

That should do the trick.

Comment: One thing to be careful about is that his iFrame has 100% width and height. Setting opacity to 0 would still overlay the iframe over the current page, preventing any clicks (esentially, click-jacking his own site), so you need to be careful about positioning and sizing of this iframe while it's hidden.

Comment: In a nutshell, the tasks i want to perform are: 1. When the page loads, load the iframe content page also but keep the iframe hidden.
2. When user clicks the magnifier image, then simply show the iframe and its contents.